# Netlify Redirects not working for Vite React app, but deploy logs say redirects processed successfully

Tags: reactjs, vite, netlify

I am trying to get my frontend code to redirect all /api requests to my backend hosted on heroku, but when I go to the deployed site it is still making a failed /api request to the netlify url rather than the heroku url I want as the proxy.

The whole reason I want to do this is that in development, I defined a proxy to my backend in the vite.config file only to find out this file is not included in the production build.

here is the fetch request I immediately make from my React app

```js
  // fetch the cookie from the server if user is logged in
  const checkAuth = async () => {
    fetch("/api/user/login", { credentials: "include" })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.data.userId) setLoggedIn(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth();
  }, []);
```

I have followed the instructions from the docs that say to place a _redirects folder in the publish directory. In my case I am just running 'vite build' which generates a dist folder, moving the _redirects file into it, and then manually pasting the dist file into netlify to deploy. It deploys successfully and the logs say all redirect rules were processed. But when I navigate to the deployed site, my initial fetch request to /api/user/login is still prefixed with the netlfiy url  rather than the heroku url which it should be proxying to.

should see a request to
`https://gentle-spire-83185-d5ea8d952a7d.herokuapp.com/api/user/login`

but in my console it is still attempting to fetch the endpoint from my netlify url
 `GET https://64cad3f677969a087f5ce558--glittering-starburst-0ee53e.netlify.app/api/user/login 404`

here is my _redirects file contents:
`/api/*  https://gentle-spire-83185-d5ea8d952a7d.herokuapp.com/:splat  200`

Why is it netlify saying my redirects were processed succesfully, but still not proxying my api requests to the heroku url?